# If I measure myself am I only measuring my size?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, italian

In Italy when people say they ***measure themselves***, they are not only measuring their height, or their waistlines. Instead they are measuring how well they do something in a challenging or difficult situation. It's like saying, I *measured* my expertise.

It is similar to *put yourself to the test* but it doesn't quite convey the same meaning. *Put yourself to the test* is about seeing where your limits lie. ***Misurarsi*** (measure oneself) on the other hand, isn't so much about competing against yourself, it's saying whether you will *sink or swim* in a specific situation. Will you cope? Do you have enough skill/knowledge/expertise to overcome this challenging episode?

I'm sure there is a phrasal verb or idiom that means you can "measure yourself" in a difficult situation, I just can't think of it.

Comment: "The ultimate *measure of a man* is not where he stands in moments of comfort and convenience, but where he stands at times of challenge and controversy." - Martin Luther King Jr.

Comment: [and dozens others](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/keywords/measure_of_a_man.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

English has an extremely similar idiom:

> Alice **measured up** the challenge before her.
>
> Bob tried to compete but didn't quite **measure up**.

Comment: Also of note is the phrase "reflection" or "self-reflection" but it really only applies to *past* events: "Charles paused for a moment of self-reflection."

Comment: Could you tell me if "She wanted to see if her English measured up" sounds idiomatic/natural?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, it sounds perfectly natural.

Answer (score 3):

If you said, "I'm taking on this challenge to measure myself." your meaning would probably be understood.  But a more accurate English translation would be "to test myself" or "to prove myself".

Answer (score 1):

'"To take measure of' someone" might be a suitable phrasing.